# Expanding a GUI tree view on Ubuntu with the keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Synaptic and Ubuntu, and when installing something it gives a tree view widget. ("To be removed", "Unchanged") where you can expand items by pressing on the `+` icon.

My question: How can I expand these items with the keyboard? On Windows, <kbd>Right</kbd> would work, but here it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> to expand and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> to contract.

Answer (score 0):

Can't try it right now, but maybe:

- <kbd>tab</kbd> to cycle the focus between the widgets and select the tree;
- <kbd>up</kbd> / <kbd>down</kbd> to select the tree items;
- <kbd>space</kbd> to expand/contract the tree items.

Comment: <kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The keys <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> work in most tree view widgets (regardless of OS) for expand and collapse, respectively.